# Bizarre data seeding error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decimal

I have a class called Order that has fields total and commission_amount, which are both decimals. In the seeds.rb file I assign both fields `100.00`, as is (no quotes). When I enter rails console and type Order.all I can see that the order created by the seeds file has a commission amount of `100.00` but the total is listed as `0.0`.
I've tried using rails console to assign different numbers to it, both total and commission amount are decimal attributes with `precision: 10, scale: 2`. I've tried using a BigDecimal constructor to assign the values in the seeds file, and I don't have any kind of verifications in place over the total attribute. Pretty stumped on what should be a trivial issue. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: here are the relevant samples of code

```rb
# the migration
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      # ...
      t.decimal :total, precision: 10, scale: 2
      t.decimal :commission_amount, precision: 10, scale: 2
    end
  end
end

# the seeds file

# Order SEEDING
# --------------
create_records([
    {
      # ...
      total: 100.00,
      commission_amount: 100.00
    }
  ], Order)
```

Comment: did you successfully try to assign the values via console or did that not work either? What is your full column definition (including defaults)? can you paste the relevant part of your seeds.rb file?

Comment: assigning through the console works for the commission_amount but not the total, and I just updated with code samples

Comment: Is that a typo in your posted migration code, or is your real code wrong too?

Comment: What is `order.total.class` (called on an order instance)?

Comment: it's telling me its a float

Comment: @davidicus what means "assigning does not work for total"? Do you get an error or does it remain zero? Can you show your model, too? Do you probably have a method called `total` defined in it? Have you verified the actual value in the db?

Comment: Oh man that was the problem, there's a method called total in the order class I didn't notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange value association errors in ActiveRecord are often caused by name collisions. ActiveRecord defines setter and getter methods for all fields in the database table of a model and ruby allows you to silently override those in your class definition.

It is always a good advice to go sure not to have used a reserved word for a column name (classic candidates are 'type','object','class'), not to have called a column the same as an associated object, and finally not to define a method with the same name as a column in the database.

In your case, check if you have defined a method called `total` in your model definition.